# Piece of iron instead of a proper fuse

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

In a video game Dying Light 2, there are those electrical boxes that you open and then "fix" by putting a piece of iron (I suppose). Assuming voltage $U$ is being produced and is supplied via the electrical box. The power dissipated on the piece of iron would be $P=\frac{U^2}{R}$ where R is the resistance of the iron.

Assuming the lengths of the iron and a thin wire inside a proper fuse are the same and the conductivities are as well the same then the resistance of the iron is smaller. That results in big power dissipation. The iron would start glowing quite rather quickly, wouldn't it? Like a broiler (grill option) in a home oven.

Of course it would be very unsafe to make such an amendment!

Is my reasoning correct?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the fuse does not quickly heat. The reason this is described as unsafe is that that now if there's an electrical problem with the device being powered by this box (like a short between live and neutral, or a short between live and a person's hand) the device will dump a ton of power into that short. *That* would make something really hot really fast, when normally a fuse would break stopping significant damage from happening. But if you find yourself in an apocalypse and you cant get ahold of the correctly rated fuse, you should go ahead and do this.

You make a mistake in assuming that there is a voltage $U$ drop across the fuse which doesn't change when you change the fuse. The whole point of a fuse is to break when the current through it exceeds a certain threshold, but to provide very low resistance otherwise. You should imagine that the fuse has a tiny resistance $r$, and it's in series with a very big resistance $R$. That's the device that you actually want power to dissipate through, the useful device being powered. Although power increases for a constant voltage when resistance decreases, if two resistors are in series, more power is dissipated through the bigger resistor.

The voltage drop $U$ is across the two resistors in series, not just the fuse. So the current is $U/(r+R)$. The power through the bigger resistor is $P_R=U^2R/(r+R)^2$, and the power through the fuse is $P_r=U^2r/(r+R)^2\ll P_R$. Indeed, making the resistance of the fuse smaller makes the power dissipating in the fuse *even smaller*, not bigger.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I confused how the power formula works. I understand your answer very well. 

Ok, so what about the fact that he puts the iron bar with bare hands? If he is not properly insulated from actual floor, he might get electrocuted, right?

Comment: @LukaszSkowron yes if the fuse touches the live end (the side that's powered) before it touches the end that goes to the device, the shortest path to ground will be through the person, and they will be electrocuted. Looks like a beefy fuse so it'll probably be a substantial shock. Typically the way you replace a fuse would involve disconnecting the fuse box from power before touching anything. I'm assuming in the game some device immediately started working when he did this, which means it was powered the whole time, and this would have been very likely to electrocute you.

Answer (score 0):

The Formula
\begin{align}
P = \frac{U^2}{R}
\end{align}
holds for $U$ being the voltage drop across the iron bar. Voltage is not "supplied" and "flows" through the iron bar. Rather, it will have a defined value at every point in the circuit, according to (with $I$ being the current flowing through the iron bar)
\begin{align}
U = R*I
\end{align}
which is the difference of voltage on the connections.

That said, the iron bar would only work to short the circuit, and thus enable operation that needs electricity. It is not a suitable replacement for a fuse, for the reason that the fuse is supposed to burn if the current is too high, removing the connection.